# Multiple stylesheets for a Lightbox clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Lightbox clone (colorbox), which works fine and has no real issues. What I would like is an extra arguement that would say:

[pseudocode]

```
if (linksRel == "lightbox1") {
  add stylesheet1 to this lightbox
} else {
  add stylesheet2 to this lightbox
}
```

[/pseudocode]

Currently, I have a page with a "colorbox.css" file attached and the" jquery.colorbox.js" file as well - But I want the JS file to import the required CSS dependant on what link was clicked... Urgh, does that make sense?

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped!

Comment: Nice FakeCode tags.  Should maybe implement them :o)

Comment: Changed to pseudocode tags ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try importing the stylesheet with jQuery like this:

```
$("#stylesheets").html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" \/>');
```

using of course some kind of click() handler on that link you want.

Comment: Hey, this looks like the code I need. However, I have added a function that is called on click but the stylesheet isn't being added to the page. Where does the #stylesheets ID come in?

Comment: #stylesheets should be the ID of a div in your HTML where the stylesheets would be inserted into. In this case you need a `<div id="stylesheets" style="display:none;"></div>`

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Also make sure you test that on a few browsers, some might not accept that kind of behaviour (adding stylesheets on the fly with JS). If the answer was helpful you can Vote Up / Accept it.